# Encrypt code files that will be available only for running and not reading - WINDOWS

Tags: windows, encryption

I have end users of my system, for run the system the end user have to run some script with bat file, the script runs some code.

I need to encrypt all the files in the directory that contains the code, including the code files and if it possible encrypt the script also.

But I want be able to run the script and the code from outside the directory, maybe with another script.

If the end user will open the directory he will see gibberish, but if he will run a script outside the directory, the code will run.

Comment: What language? Perhaps you should post this on StackOverflow instead

Comment: @golimar its not a code problem.
its an accessing problem. so the language is not relevant, I want to encrypt also the bash script. there is an option to encrypt the files, but cant run them.

Comment: Is this not pretty much the definition of a compiled .exe ?

Comment: @Tetsujin not compiling.

Comment: yet that's what you're describing… something that can execute code without users being able to see what's inside it...

Comment: @Tetsujin imagine a bash script that I want to encrypt but only to be able to run it without read it.

Comment: @GuyCohen - What you describe doesn't exist.

Comment: It's possible to pack all the files into one executable (or compiled script), so they are not visible as files.